# SASS mixing and passing a variable string that's a function name

Tags: sass

I'm expanding out a SASS mixin for generating background colours.

Here's my mixin:

```css
@mixin color-columns ($count, $baseName, $startcolor) {
  $loop_color : $startcolor;
  @for $i from 0 through $count {
    $loop_color : darken($loop_color, 8%);
    .#{$baseName}-#{$i} {
      background-color : $loop_color;
    }
  }
}
```

And i use it like this:

```css
@include color-columns(5,'col', $blue);
```

What I want to do is pass in either 'darken' or 'lighten' as a variable so i can control with SASS colour function. Something like this:

```css
@mixin color-columns ($count, $baseName, $startcolor, $change: 'darken') {
  $loop_color : $startcolor;
  
  @for $i from 0 through $count {
    $loop_color : $change($loop_color, 8%);
    .#{$baseName}-#{$i} {
      background-color : $loop_color;
    }
  }
}
```

When i try that, my CSS for the first column is like this:

```css
    background-color: darken darken #005387, 8%, 8%;
```

I'm missing the connection on passing a variable that swaps the function.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no support for defining dynamic function names. It has been [requested several years ago](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/626) and there is even an [open pull request](https://github.com/sass/sass/pull/2057) for this functionality but it is not yet merged.

However, it is possible to *dynamically call a function* with the built-in [`call($function, $args...)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#call-instance_method) function. It allows you to avoid if-else cascades and can be used in your example like this:

`$loop_color : call($change, $loop_color, 8%);`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding an @if to get this to work:

```css
@mixin color-columns ($count, $startcolor, $start : darken) {
  $loop_color : $startcolor;

  @if $start == 'lighten' {
    @for $i from 0 through $count {
      $loop_color : lighten($loop_color, 5%);
      .conBG-#{$i} {
        background-color : $loop_color;
      }
    }
  }
  @else {
    @for $i from 0 through $count {
      $loop_color : darken($loop_color, 5%);
      .conBG-#{$i} {
        background-color : $loop_color;
      }
    }
  }
}
```